# jQuery .stop() on scroll is blocking animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my simple scroll function.

When user scrolls a certain distance from the bottom of the page, a registration box appears via animation:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if($docHeight - $top < 500 && document.cookie.indexOf("flag") < 0) {
            $('.register').stop().animate({
                'bottom': -1,
            });
          return false;
    }

});
```

My problem is that the .stop() function before .animate() triggers every time the user scrolls; and so during animation it is constantly stopping as the user scrolls causing a 'juddering' effect (of course, no juddering if the user doesn't scroll).

I have thought about setting flags during animation and not running the animation to avoid this, but I can't figure it out.

I believe the function .once() could be used well here?

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to animate with the user, or can it animate once scrolling stops?

Comment: It really needs to animate immediately once the if condition is met. But then for the function to basically be 'killed' to avoid running again.

Comment: You can use `.is()` with the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to test whether the animation is already in progress, and if so don't do anything. (By the way, surely that's not your whole function, given that the `$docHeight` and `$top` variables are not set within the function? Regarding the flag from the cookie, might be better to just remove the entire scroll handler when the flag is set, rather than testing it on every scroll event.)

Comment: Thanks, and yes; those variables are set within the function.

I want to set a flag within the animation by setting a variable to true. How do I then get that variable outside of the function to test against for the scroll handler?

Comment: You'd have to declare the variable outside the function for it to be available outside the function. I just meant `if($docHeight - $top < 500 && document.cookie.indexOf("flag") < 0 && !$('.register').is(':animated')) {`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks; was not aware of that function/selector. Does the trick.

Comment: By the way, setting `var register = $('.register')` outside the scroll handler and then using `!register.is(':animated')` in the `if` would be more efficient then reselecting the element on every scroll.

Comment: Thank you, great advice.